# “Ich mag programmieren.” – why not “möchte”?

Tags: english-to-german, tense

I am writing a short self-indroduction for my German A1.1 Class, and I need to say this sentence:

> I like to program (programming), watch NBA and read science books.

As I looked at some translators, the “best” solution for the first part seemed to be:

> Ich mag programmieren.

Why should I use *mag* and not *möchte?*

Comment: Why do you think that you should use "möchte"? _(I think you mean "möchte" and not "mochte")_

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I further edited your question to reduce it to a single issue. Please ask your second question (about watching NBA) separately. Also, are you sure that you want to replace *mag* with *mochte* and not *möchte?*

Comment: Going back to your original sentence. *Ich programmiere gern* is a more idiomatic way of translating it

Comment: Translator programmes are a pest. People take the weirdest translations from them. - I am working EU wide with variuos organisations, and they sometimes send me project exposés they wrote in, say, Italian, and think they help me by feeding it into Google translate for English. Really, the Italian original is easier to understand than what they get back as "English". - Don't use translator programmes for languages you do not know!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Ich **möchte** = I **want to** + simple form

  > Ich möchte programmieren = I want to program.
  >   Ich möchte schlafen. = I want to sleep.
  >   Ich möchte essen. = I want to eat.
- Ich **mag** = I **like** + progressive form

  > Ich mag programmieren = I like programming.
  >   Ich mag schlafen. = I like sleeping.
  >   Ich mag essen. = I like eating.

Comment: »Ich mag schlafen« or »Ich mag essen« isn’t really well-formed German.

Comment: Bavarian "I mog di" ("Ich mag dich") is equivalent to "I love you".

Comment: Mag kommt von mögen und kann auch als Vorliebe zu etwas gedeutet werden. In diesem Sinne würde ich im englischen eher "i enjoy coding, sleeping, eating." schreiben. "Ich möchte" ist auch nicht so stark wie "ich will" und sollte im englischen dann eher als "i would like to" statt "I want to" übersetzt werden.

Answer (score 6):

"Mag" is present tense, "mochte" is past tense.
Or do you mean "möchte". That's to express your intention as in "I would like to"
or "I want to".

Comment: Yes I meant möchte, ah okay so I've been using möchte wrong for the last month then haha. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Ich mag programmieren = I like programming (and I am able to do it)
Ich möchte programmieren = I want to programm (but I may have to learn it before, or I have to buy a compiler before). You may say to a waiter ich möchte etwas essen when you are hungry and you would like to order something to eat.

Answer (score 1):

The best translation for I have found for `möchte` is `I would like to`. On the other hand `mag` can be equal to `I like`.

> Ich möchte programmieren = I would like to program.
>
> Ich mag programmieren    = I like programming